# How tell command (on page) which control was pressed?

Tags: xamarin.forms, mvvm, navigation, prism

i have a big knot in my brain.
The current Situation is the following:

in my xamarin Forems App i have on some Pages a UserControl (House) witch Contains multiple Controls (Floor) and this has also multiple Controls (Rooms) in it.

This is all working perfectly and i have coll control for each room over a HouseControler Class

On my RoomControl i have:

```
    <Grid.GestureRecognizers>
       <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding Source={x:Reference Root}, Path=RoomTappedCommand}" />
    </Grid.GestureRecognizers>
```

this is totally perfekt. and i got my command perfectly fired in the Breakpoint.

But what i want to acheve is to open nut just an alert but a custom Popup with a Navigation from the current Page with the Informations of the Tapped Room.
So in need do pass somehow the informations from the RoomControl up to the Page. But i dont know how.

i would love to read some tipps.
Thank you Guys =)

Comment: Also note that Command allows a CommandParameter that you can pass data in, such as the room information

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Xamarin - CollectionView, pass current item as a command parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63699399/xamarin-collectionview-pass-current-item-as-a-command-parameter). `CommandParameter={Binding .}`

Answer (score 0):

you can always get a reference to the currently active page using `App.Current.MainPage`.  To display an alert, for example

```
App.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert(...);
```

Comment: Hi, i am totally sorry. i want to open a compleate custom PopupPage with navigation. i forgott to mention this. 

but an alert is a good first step

Comment: Using `PushModalAsync`, or something else?  Your question is very short on details